# Wireless Multicast transmission

Tags: wireless-networking, ip, routing, bandwidth, multicast

I'm working on a high bandwidth application which uses multicast.

Let's say there's 20 ip devices connected wireless to a router.  One ip device sends a multicast packet to the multicast group.  Will the wireless router only forward that packet once to the group, or will the router send that packet 20 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will send it only once to the group, but it will send it at the *multicast rate*, which is generally the lowest rate allowed on the network, so that even clients at the extreme edges of the network can receive them reliably. You see, multicasts don't get Ack'ed at the 802.11 layer, so they don't get 802.11-layer retransmission, so to make sure distant clients receive them reliably they're sent at lower data rates that use simpler modulation schemes that work under the worst signal-to-noise ratios (SNRs).

So, for example, if you have a current state-of-the-art 1300Mbps 802.11ac network, and you have legacy 802.11n and 802.11a rates enabled for the same of maximum usable range, the AP might transmit your multicast at 802.11a's lowest data rate of 6Mbps, taking over 216x as much airtime as the fastest clients' 1300Mbps unicasts.

Comment: Ah great, that should work for my needs. Thank you.